# While running my testcase in Jenkins getting below error "java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter"

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I am new to jenkins. I have installed jenkins and plugins. And port 8080 I am using it. While running my test case in Jenkins I am getting below error "java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter".

### I am using TestNG . But the same is running fine when I am running in Eclipse by run as TestNG. Please help me to resolve this.

```
    java.lang.AssertionError: Unsupported type parameter : class com.volvo.tests.properties.ChosenWebDriver
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.convertType(Parameters.java:246)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:165)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:355)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    [TestNG]    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)

-------------------------------------------
```

"ChosenWebDriver"

```java
package com.volvo.tests.properties;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public enum ChosenWebDriver {

    IE("IE"), CHROME("CHROME"), Firefox("FF");
    private final String chosenDriver;

    private ChosenWebDriver(String driver) {
        chosenDriver = driver;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        WebDriver ret = null;

        switch (chosenDriver) {
        case "IE":
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
            capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
            // capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,
            // "http://www.bing.com/");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
            // capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION,
            // true);
            ret = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
            break;
        case "CHROME":

            try {
                if (Platform.getCurrent() != null && Platform.getCurrent().is(Platform.LINUX)) {
                    ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File(
                        "/usr/bin/chromedriver")).usingAnyFreePort().withLogFile(new File("/home/jenkins/.config/google-chrome/chromedriver.log")).build();
                    chromeDriverService.start();
                    ret = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, getChromeCapabilities());
                } else {
                    /*
                     * ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                     * .usingDriverExecutable(new File("selenium_drivers/chromedriver.exe")).usingAnyFreePort()
                     * .withLogFile(new File("selenium_drivers/chromedriver.log")).build();
                     * chromeDriverService.start();
                     */
                    ret = new ChromeDriver();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "FF":
            ret = new FirefoxDriver();
            break;
        }

        return ret;
    }

    // Setting Chrome desired capabilities:
    private DesiredCapabilities getChromeCapabilities() {
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
        // "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile",
        // "/home/jenkins/.config/google-chrome/chromedriver.log");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        // capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Linux
        // 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 x86_64");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.getCurrent());
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, getChromeOptions());
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.TAKES_SCREENSHOT, true);
        capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        return capabilities;
    }

    // Setting Chrome options:
    private ChromeOptions getChromeOptions() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // options.addArguments("user-data-dir=".concat("/home/jenkins/.config/google-chrome"));
        options.addArguments("profile-directory=".concat("Default"));
        options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("disable-plugins");
        options.addArguments("headless");
        options.addArguments("window-size=1920x1080");
        options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("enable-logging --v=4");
        // options.setBinary(new File("/usr/bin/google-chrome-beta"));
        return options;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using maven to perform the build in jenkins?  if so can you run the maven build locally without issue?

Comment: Hi Churd, I am new to jenkins. I am using "clean compile test" in build goal. Can you tell me how to run maven build locally ?

Comment: @churd - Please edit your question and the configuration method that is using `ChosenWebDriver`. The stacktrace suggests that the problem is stemming from your configuration method.

Comment: @ Krishnan. I have attached ChosenWebDriver. Can you please let me know which is wrong in that ?